# LINQ DateTimes between hours with duration

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a query that return dates that occur within a certain hour of the day plus duration. For example, any `DateTime`s that occur after (8PM + 8 hours), the hour and duration are variable. It is possible that hour + duration can be in the next day. A spike:

```
[Test]
public void should_find_dates_between_beginhour_plus_duration()
{
    var dates = new []
    {
                new DateTime(2017, 1, 3, 12,0,0),
                new DateTime(2017, 1, 4, 21,0,0),
                new DateTime(2017, 1, 5, 2,0,0)
    };

    var beginHour = 20; //8pm
    var duration = 8; //hours

    var results = dates.Where(x => x.Hour >= beginHour && x <= x.???? + duration);

    //should contain the last 2 dates

    foreach (var date in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Date does not matter? Only hour?

Comment: How about `x.AddHours(duration)`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy the hour + duration can go into the next "day".  Should be included in the result.

Comment: @mxmissile but start date does not matter?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy correct

Comment: @JSteward I tried that, but its only returning the 2nd DateTime, should return 2nd and 3rd. `x.Hour >= beginHour` kills `AddHours` I think.

Comment: @mxmissile should it take care of winter/summer time changes?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy nah, not important for this

Comment: @mxmissile Why the third DateTime should be returned?

Comment: because 8pm + 8 hours falls into the next "date"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thus winter/summer time shift does not important here, then you can calculate end hour before running your query. Filtering will be simple - you pick dates which have hour either bigger than begin hour (later in the evening), or smaller than end hour (i.e. earlier in the morning):

```
var endHour = DateTime.Today.AddHours(beginHour + duration).Hour;
var results = dates.Where(x => beginHour < endHour
                  ? (beginHour <= x.Hour && x.Hour <= endHour)
                  : (beginHour <= x.Hour || x.Hour <= endHour));
```

Comment: and I thought this was going to be a hard one, spisobo

Comment: Doesn't seem to work though, on this little test i made http://rextester.com/NKT68441

Comment: @Isac true, thanks. I have missed the case when end hour falls into same day. Updated solution

Comment: Finally got around to implementing this and just discovered the same thing, was just coming to update. Thanks all!